# Set Jersey to Default to JSON

Tags: jersey, jackson

I am using Jersey with Jackson. I want to default all endpoints (defined or not) to return JSON.

Let's say I have an /hello endpoint that produces application/json over GET. Now if I were to call /hello with POST, it is returning XML.

How does one configure this to default to JSON instead of XML?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to this. I have not tested this yet, but am pretty sure this will work.

```
@Provider
public class CommonExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        return Response.status(statusCode).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(restError).build();
    }
}
```

I was missing the `.type()`.